# is treating first order differential equations as results of chain rule valid?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

The entire treatise of differential equations seems obscure to me, it doesn't really have a foundation from which you can work from, as differentiation or integration do (that I know of--at least), like the difference quotient definition of a derivative, and infinite series definition of the Riemann integral.
But nonetheless, I tried to make sense of how you could work out a differential equation given only standard knowledge of differentiation/integration, and it follows as such:

The question asks to find $y$ such that:

$$ \frac{dy}{dx} = (2x + 3)\sqrt{y}$$

Now, this is a simple question, but if you notice that the RHS product *could* resemble a product of the chain rule, i.e. something of the form $[f(g(x))]' = g'(x)f'(g(x))$, now pick $g'(x) = \sqrt{y}$ and $f'(g(x) = 2x + 3$, then immediately you can solve $g(x) = \frac{2\sqrt{y^3}}{3} + c_0$, but then we have:

$$ \begin{align}
f'(g(x)) = f'\left(\frac{2\sqrt{y^3}}{3}\right) &= 2x + 3 \\
\therefore f(g(x)) = f\left(\frac{2\sqrt{y^3}}{3}\right) &= x^2 + 3x + c_1
\end{align}
$$

But this is not the answer, and resources don't seem to be abundant on this particular way of reasoning about ODEs, but I guess that the obstacle is to do with the fact that I am integrating with respect to $x$ in the second step on a function whose input is not necessarily dependent (?) on $x$, though I'm stuck.

If this method is aimless, then my question is to ask whether any related methods exist?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you did in computing your $f$ and $g$? In particular, you said pick $g'(x) = \sqrt{y}$, but the argument is $x$ and somehow the out is in $y$. What do you mean?

Comment: Honestly it isn't an assumption I thought about too much, I assumed that since $y$ is a function on $x$ to begin with, then it would be possible to solve for $y$ after reverse-chain-ruling the entire expression in some way; but that might be the issue.

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be major conceptual flaws in your working. For instance, how do you go from:

$\displaystyle g'(x) = \sqrt{y}$

to $\displaystyle g(x) = \frac{2\sqrt{y^3}}{3} + c_0$ ?

You are integrating wrt $\displaystyle x$ on the LHS, but wrt $\displaystyle y$ on the RHS.

Basically, this equation is immediately solvable by separation of variables. What you must realise is that separation of variables *is* already based on the chain rule!

The whole point of ordinary differential equations is to try to get $\displaystyle y$ as a function of $\displaystyle x$, basically to find the function $h$ where $\displaystyle y=h(x)$.

So if you're given a simple ODE like $\displaystyle \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{f(x)}{g(y)}$

You can then write $\displaystyle \frac{d}{dx}h(x) = \frac{f(x)}{g(y)}$

and proceed $\displaystyle h'(x) = \frac{f(x)}{g(y)}$ (from this point on, the prime notation denotes differentiation wrt $\displaystyle x$).

$\displaystyle h'(x)g(y) = f(x)$

$\displaystyle h'(x)g(h(x)) = f(x)$

At this point, by the (reverse of) chain rule, you should observe the LHS is the derivative of $\displaystyle G(h(x))$ wrt $\displaystyle x$, where $\displaystyle G'(x) = g(x)$ giving:

$\displaystyle h'(x) G'(h(x)) = f(x)$

$\displaystyle (G(h(x))'= f(x)$

$\displaystyle G(h(x)) = F(x) + c$

where $\displaystyle F'(x) = f(x)$.

and finally $\displaystyle y = h(x) = G^{-1}(F(x)+c)$.

assuming $\displaystyle G$ is invertible.

So separation of variables is already rooted in the application of chain rule. Our "normal" working by separating $\displaystyle y$ and $\displaystyle x$ to opposite sides is simply a shorthand representation that works.

Answer (score 0):

The form of the chain rule you need to be using is that which you learned in multivariable calculus, an exact differential:

\begin{align}\tag{1}
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\lambda(x,y)=\frac{\partial \lambda}{\partial y}\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}+\frac{\partial \lambda}{\partial x}.
\end{align}
You can read about it on the wiki page for chain rule or just google "multivariable chain rule". Rewriting your ODE gives
\begin{align}\tag{2}
\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}-(2x+3)\sqrt y=0,
\end{align}
which is similar in form to Eqn. (1), so we'll begin with the ansatz that Eqn. (2) is indeed an exact differential, so then it must be that
\begin{align}
1&=\frac{\partial \lambda}{\partial y},\ \ \ \ \text{and}\\
-(2x+3)\sqrt y&=\frac{\partial \lambda}{\partial x}.
\end{align}
If we integrate the first Eqn. we see that
\begin{align}
\lambda(x,y)=y+f(x),
\end{align}
where $f(x)$ is an arbitrary function picked up from integrating with respect to $y$. Taking a derivative with respect to $x$ and setting it equal to the other equation we get that
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm df}{\mathrm dx}=-(2x+3)\sqrt y.
\end{align}
But $f(x)$ is only a function of $x$, therefore the ansatz that Eqn. (2) is a perfect differential was wrong.

That being said, multiplying the entire equation by a integrating factor $m(x,y)$ sometimes makes your ODE a perfect differential, you can read about that by googling "exact differential equation integrating factor"